# belongsToMany не работает

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, relation

У меня есть 3 таблицы

```
videos (id)
video_user (user_id, video_id)
users (id)
```

Мне нужно чтобы я мог получить все видео, которые опубликовал пользователь

---

Я уже попытался это сделать таким образом:

User.php (Модель)

```
public function videos() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Video::class);
}
```

Video.php (Модель)

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

Но этот вариант ничего не возвращает

Comment: Название у промежуточной таблицы "является производной от алфавитного порядка имен связанных моделей". Получается что должно быть `user_video`. Либо просто указать навазвание таблицы во втором параметре у `belongsToMany`

Comment: @Knyaz71 
Спасибо за ответ. Но каким образом мне взаимодействовать с ними? Я изменил на user_video, но при вызове обеих функций - вывода все-равно нет, несмотря на то, что в таблице есть записи, подходящие по критериям

Comment: К примеру, `$user = User::with('videos')->first(); foreach($user->videos as $video){ dump($video); }`

Comment: @Knyaz71 Спасибо большое за ответ, это решило мою проблему, если вы вынесете комментарий в ответ - я помечу его как ответ на мой вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если в `belongsToMany` явно не указывать таблицу (вторым параметром), то она определяется как "производная от алфавитного порядка имен связанных моделей".

Получается что промежуточная таблица должна быть `user_video`.
Либо просто указать название таблицы во втором параметре

```php
$this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'video_user');
```

Дальнейшее использование, например...

```php
$user = User::with('videos')->first();
foreach ($user->videos as $video) {
    dump($video);
}
```

По сути `with` можно не указывать. Но на сколько знаю, разница в том, что при указании `with` сразу подгружает данные, а без указания - по необходимости.